# Morphology software for English

Tags: nlp

In my application I need to use a piece of software able to: a) convert the words to their basic forms and b) find if they are 'nouns', 'verbs' etc.

I found a list of software able to do that job.

http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Morphology_software_for_English

Does anyone have any experience with any of these? Which one do you recommend?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Python) to perform these tasks.

> Find if they are 'nouns', 'verbs'...

This task is called the [Part-of-speech tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging). You can use the `nltk.pos_tag` function. (See the [Peen Treebank tagset](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html))

> Convert the words to their basic forms

This task is called [lemmatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation). You can use the `nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize` function.

**Example**

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

penn_to_wn = lambda penn_tag: {'NN':wn.NOUN,'JJ':wn.ADJ,'VB':wn.VERB,'RB':wn.ADV}.get(penn_tag[:2], wn.NOUN)

sentence = "The rabbits are eating in the garden."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
wl = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmas = [wl.lemmatize(token, pos=penn_to_wn(tag)) for token, tag in pos_tags]
```

Then if you print the results:

```
>>> tokens
['The', 'rabbits', 'are', 'eating', 'in', 'the', 'garden', '.']

>>> pos_tags
[('The', 'DT'),
 ('rabbits', 'NNS'),
 ('are', 'VBP'),
 ('eating', 'VBG'),
 ('in', 'IN'),
 ('the', 'DT'),
 ('garden', 'NN'),
 ('.', '.')]

>>> lemmas
['The', u'rabbit', u'be', u'eat', 'in', 'the', 'garden', '.']
```

Comment: What's the difference between `Morphology software` and `lemmatization`? Also, do you have any idea how this can be done in C or C++?

Comment: @SilverWarrior I don't know what is `Morphology_software`. Where did you see this? Lemmatization is the process of grouping together the different inflected forms of a word so they can be analysed as a single item (Wikipedia).
Usually, Natural Language Processing tasks are performed using Python, Java or Perl... But you might find some equivalent tools for C++ [in this Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_natural_language_processing#Natural_language_processing_toolkits).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, seems like you know your stuff. Right now I am using this software http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kieliteknologia/tutkimus/hfst/ (here is a demo http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/cgi-bin/omor/omordemo.bash?wf=having&language=en&function=morphology&variant=apertium-mk-en ). It can convert 'trying' to 'try' etc. What I am trying to do is group words that have the same meaning together. Do you think I should use something from this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_natural_language_processing#Natural_language_processing_toolkits ?

Comment: @SilverWarrior [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) provides for each word a set of synonyms (called "synset"). [Here](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/frequently-asked-questions/for-application-developer/) they talk about a C API. Wordnet is for Java but everybody use it through API as it is a very powerful library.